# How to tell the difference between changed and added lines?

Tags: text-processing, csv, diff

I have two csv files where I want to figure out the deleted, modified and added lines. (The first field is an unique id.)

The first file looks like:

```
0, WILL_BE_REMOVED
1, OLD
2, SAME
3, SAME
```

and a newer csv file:

```
1, CHANGED
2, SAME
3, SAME
4, ADDED
5, ADDED
```

I was thinking that `diff` might tell me that, yet when I run:

```
diff newer_file.csv  older_file.csv 
1c1,2
< 1, CHANGED
---
> 0, WILL_BE_REMOVED
> 1, OLD
4,5c5
< 4, ADDED
< 5, ADDED
---
>
```

I see a changed line similar as an added line. Is there a way to distinguish between changes and additions?

Can I achieve what I want with diff? If not, could some other bash tool fit my use case?

```
DELETED: 0, WILL_BE_REMOVED
UPDATED: 1, CHANGED
ADDED 4,
ADDED 5,
```

Comment: `diff` will not know that the ID in the first field is what decides the "identity" of a line.  If like in your example the ID fields are unique and monotonically increasing, and the first file is small enough to fit in memory, it should be easy to create a simple Awk script which prints your expected output.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `-c` option (copied context) will allow you to distinguish between changes and additions:

```
diff -c older_file.csv newer_file.csv
```

produces (after the header)

```
*** 1,4 ****
! 0, WILL_BE_REMOVED
! 1, OLD
  2, SAME
  3, SAME
--- 1,5 ----
! 1, CHANGED
  2, SAME
  3, SAME
+ 4, ADDED
+ 5, ADDED
```

Changes lines start with `!`, added lines start with `+`. Deleted lines start with `-`.

`diff` can “merge” changes, so it might end up considering that added lines are part of a larger change, and mark everything with `!`. You can see this above where the deleted line is considered part of the larger change affecting the first two lines, and thus ends up marked `!` instead of `-`.

Side-by-side comparisons (`diff -y`) help highlight some of the issues with what you’re trying to achieve:

```
0, WILL_BE_REMOVED    | 1, CHANGED
1, OLD                <
2, SAME                 2, SAME
3, SAME                 3, SAME
                      > 4, ADDED
                      > 5, ADDED
```

`diff` isn’t aware of the internal structure of individual lines, so it can’t determine which of the first two lines in the older file is deleted, or even whether it should consider that two lines were deleted and one added, instead of one deleted and one changed.

Comment: Nice to learn something new. I'd not realised the context diff showed changed lines as I've long since moved on to unified diffs.

Answer (score 1):

A great tool to do it is daff http://paulfitz.github.io/daff/

A sort of diff specialized on CSV.

Answer (score 0):

`diff` works on lines. If the line is different it is expressed in terms of a deletion and an addition.

I don't know of a tool that can comprehend the concept of "changed". Consider, if you changed a line from `red` to `yellow` how would *you* (as a person) determine whether the `red` line had been deleted and a `yellow` one added, or the same line changed in its entirety?

On a related side issue, personally I prefer the unified diff. I find it far more readable than an `ed` script. With your example data it would be expressed like this:

```
diff -u older_file.csv newer_file.csv
--- older_file.csv      2019-02-04 12:23:32.416529000 +0000
+++ newer_file.csv      2019-02-04 12:23:41.551570700 +0000
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
-0, WILL_BE_REMOVED
-1, OLD
+1, CHANGED
 2, SAME
 3, SAME
+4, ADDED
+5, ADDED
```